# Attaching Lower Impedance Part to a Function Generator

Tags: impedance, sine, function-generator

If a speaker with a hypothetical 3 ohm impedance is attached a signal generator with an output impedance of 50 ohms, will the speaker draw too much current, and overload the signal generator?

Answer (score 1):

No, most signal generators can handle a short on the output - 3 Ω is slightly 'easier'.

Comment: I see. I've been told that function generators shouldn't be used to drive speakers though, is it due to the generator functioning poorly when shorted?

Comment: @itisyeetimetoday A good quality - ie a name you have heard of - function generator will simply act as a voltage source in series with a 50 ohm resistor. If loaded by a short or 3 ohms, it will simply drive the appropriate current into it without fuss. If it's a cheap function generator only available through online sources, then maybe it will behave well, maybe not. However, even with a good quality one, the output power will be very low, so you may want to use an amplifier between generator and speaker, depending on your application.